# Why does compiler not see @synthesize and @dynamic?

Tags: cocoa, macos, llvm, clang

This is NOT new code.  It has been compiled and executed successfully thousands of times BEFORE OS 10.7 Lion/LLVM/Clang.

```
@interface CapDuring : NSObject {
    const char * iFileName;
...
}
@property(assign) const char * iFileName;
...
@property(readonly,getter=iFileName) const char * fileName;
```

!Property 'fileName' requires method 'iFileName' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation

```
...
@end


@implementation CapDuring
@synthesize iFileName;
...
@end
```

This warning is repeated for every declaration like it (even if @dynamic is used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got around this error by moving any properties which use getters that are also properties into a separate @interface MyClass ( myCompile ).

This same issue arrises when an OS property/method is renamed via a getter/setter.

I got around that by eliminating the renaming of OS methods.

Thank you for all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Your line here is `@synthesize iFileName`. That's incorrect. You want `@synthesize fileName`. You're synthesizing the property, not the method. The method itself is generated as part of the process of synthesizing the property accessors.

Answer (score 2):

```
@property(readonly,getter=iFileName) const char * fileName;
@synthesize iFileName;
```

means that there's a property called filename that takes its getter as named "iFileName".

and there is really no synthesize for that property

i guess what you want to do is define the getter name of iFileName as "fileName", that's :

```
@property(readonly,getter=fileName) const char * iFileName;
@synthesize iFileName;
```

which makes a getter named fileName for the property iFileName by synthesize

Answer (score 1):

Using 
@property(...) ... iInstanceVariable
and then
@property(...,getter=iInstance) ... instanceReference
into a separate @interface ( category ) began to give me problems.

The best solution is:

@property(...) ... instanceReference;
@synthesize instanceReference = iInstanceVariable;

This works without fail within a separate category or not.